# .NET Event handler on a database object

Tags: .net, sql-server

I want to reduce polling in my application solution (many apps, 1 database, some 3rd party), customer wants an up-to-the-second GUI status of whats going on. Is it possible to add an event handler through .NET code to a table or database using SQL Server technologies?

Here are some solutions I've come across:

- SQL Server Service Broker with external activation - only launches new applications, not really an "event handler" kind of scenario
- CLR stored procedures - limited in functionality, obviously will have same issue getting event to the GUI status screen
- Go custom - I could do something crazy like having the SQL Server create a file (using XP command shell) in a folder with a trigger when a qualified event occurs, then have a `FileSystemWatcher` object pick up the file change event and trigger it that way, but that smells bad somehow.

Comment: I was thinking about this problem a few days ago, in my case I need to be able to notify when a db object's definition changes. I was wondering if it would be possible to add a cache dependency on a table or view and use that to track when things change. Might be worth investigating. Or it too might ultimately smell pretty eggy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx

Comment: Why can't you just query sys.objects for anything that's been modified in the last x?

Comment: because that is polling.  if I check the database every single second to see if something has changed to get the desired effect, then that is a lot of extra work for the server.  Having something notify you when what you're watching for happens is much more efficient.  Push/Pull.

Comment: Apologies, I meant SqlDependency (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.90).aspx). Thanks @ChrisShain ;-)

I'm waiting for his response before I begin looking into this for my purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx).  The only caveat is that, as the docs state,

> SqlDependency was designed to be used in ASP.NET or middle-tier
>   services where there is a relatively small number of servers having
>   dependencies active against the database. It was not designed for use
>   in client applications, where hundreds or thousands of client
>   computers would have SqlDependency objects set up for a single
>   database server. If you are developing an application where you need
>   reliable sub-second notifications when data changes, review the
>   sections Planning an Efficient Query Notifications Strategy and
>   Alternatives to Query Notifications in the Planning for Notifications
>   topic in SQL Server Books Online.

In general though I find the above statement to be true for most SQL Server client applications, so hopefully this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: No :-)  Although sql cache dependency and sqldependency are not precisely the same thing.

Comment: Damn it you're right. I think I did mean SqlDependency. Do you think this is a sensible way for @Jrud and I to proceed? And I notice the MSDN docs only refer to 2008 - is there a newer mechanism for the latest db version?

Comment: It is available for SQL 2008 R2 (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110(v=sql.105).aspx) and while the docs are not complete for 2012 I'm sure it works for that as well.